# IIS String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, iis

I have an issue,

I have string date with this format `dd/MM/yyyy` and then convert it to DateTime object using `Convert.ToDateTime(date)` it run just fine within VS but when I publish it to IIS it always throws `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

but if change the format to `MM/dd/yyyy` it runs fine in IIS but error if run it via VS.

```
string date =  "19/9/2019"  //"dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date); //run fine via VS, error in IIS

string date = "09/19/2019" //"MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date); //run fine via IIS, error in VS
```

please advice

Comment: Try using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You can try [DateTim.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `"09/19/yyyy"` is *not* a valid string that can be parsed to `DateTime`, and it should throw exception on IIS either.

Second, [`Convert.ToDateTime(string)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) uses [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8) settings on your machine. If your VS and IIS in different machines, check their `CurrentCulture` settings on both machines. I assume they are quite diferent and one of them is not have `"dd/M/yyyy"` as a standart date format.

On the other hand, to prevent this kind of parsing operations, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact` method overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and you can specify exact format and proper (that uses `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator?view=netframework-4.8)) culture information.

Aslo be aware that the diffence between [`M`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#M_Specifier) and [`MM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier) specifiers. For single digit month numbers, `MM` specifier will generate month number with leading zero (like `09`) but `M` specifier won't.

```
string date =  "19/9/2019";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("dd/M/yyyy", date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
string date =  "19/09/2019";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("dd/MM/yyyy", date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: sorry  typo, it should be 09/19/2019 not 09/2019/yyyy

Comment: thanks, you point me to right direction, I change my IIS culture and now the error is gone

Answer (score 1):

You getting error just because server-side default culture is different from development site.

You should either use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or use `DateTime.TryParse` specifying the appropriate `CultureInfo`. 
(For E.g., the culture of the user.)

You should apply an appropriate `CultureInfo` to `ToString` - possibly `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Example:

```
var varDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt3 = Convert.ToDateTime(varDate);
```